# How to remove a specific component in React? (Using key and id)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was going through the React docs and was attempting to modify a TodoList Item.
https://codesandbox.io/s/43njy6458x

I am trying to remove each component with a button, however the button does not delete the item.
I have tried a few methods to filter the list, yet none have successfully accomplished the function.

```
    const ToDo = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>{props.id}</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>{props.createdAt.toTimeString()}</label>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={props.deleteItem}
        value={props.id}
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
);

class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const date = new Date();
    const toDoCounter = 1;
    this.state = {
      list: [
        {
          id: toDoCounter,
          createdAt: date,
        },
      ],
      toDoCounter: toDoCounter,
    };
  }

  sortByEarliest() {
    const sortedList = this.state.list.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.createdAt - b.createdAt;
    });
    this.setState({
      list: [...sortedList],
    });
  }

  sortByLatest() {
    const sortedList = this.state.list.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.createdAt - a.createdAt;
    });
    this.setState({
      list: [...sortedList],
    });
  }

  addToEnd() {
    const date = new Date();
    const nextId = this.state.toDoCounter + 1;
    const newList = [
      ...this.state.list,
      {id: nextId, createdAt: date},
    ];
    this.setState({
      list: newList,
      toDoCounter: nextId,
    });
  }

  addToStart() {
    const date = new Date();
    const nextId = this.state.toDoCounter + 1;
    const newList = [
      {id: nextId, createdAt: date},
      ...this.state.list,
    ];
    this.setState({
      list: newList,
      toDoCounter: nextId,
    });
  }
// this is the issue
  deleteItem(event) {

    const clickedId = event.target.value;
    //console.log(clickedId);
    const arrDes = [...this.state.list];
    const newList = this.state.list.filter((item) => {

    //console.log(item.id);
    return item.id !== clickedId;
    })
    this.setState({
      list: newList
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <code>key=id index=id</code>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.addToStart.bind(this)}>
          Add New to Start
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.addToEnd.bind(this)}>
          Add New to End
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.sortByEarliest.bind(this)}>
          Sort by Earliest
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.sortByLatest.bind(this)}>
          Sort by Latest
        </button>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th />
            <th>created at</th>
          </tr>
          {this.state.list.map((todo, index) => (
            <ToDo key={todo.id} value={todo.id} deleteItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this)} {...todo} />


          ))}
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Isolated code in question:

```
    // this is the issue

    deleteItem(event) {

    const clickedId = event.target.value;
    //console.log(clickedId);
    const arrDes = [...this.state.list];
    const newList = this.state.list.filter((item) => {

    //console.log(item.id);
    return item.id !== clickedId;
    })
    this.setState({
      list: newList
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `clickedId` to a natural number to match the `id` of the list element:

```
const newList = this.state.list.filter(item => {
    return item.id !== +clickedId      
});
```

The `+` operator is one way to do that.

Comment: This explains where I went wrong. How would have I found this on my own?

Comment: @K.Arthur I did console.log(this.state.list, clickedId) and noticed the Id mismatch.  It was subtle for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your function can be simplified:

```
deleteItem(event) {

  // Grab the value from the clicked button by
  // using destructuring to pick out that property 
  const { value } = event.target;

  // return an array that doesn't include objects with ids
  // that match the value - coerced to a number from a string
  // so it matches the id type in your data
  const newList = this.state.list.filter(item => item.id !== Number(value));
  this.setState({ list: newList });
}
```

Comment: I am grateful for the explanation. It provides a lot of information that I much needed. Any links where I can learn more of this on my own? Thank you.

Comment: Here's [documentation on destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).